# How do I test if a specific tag of a docker image already exists in gcr.io?

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I've noticed with `gcr.io` that when I push a docker image with a specific tag:

```
gcr.io/myproject/myimage:mytag
```

If that image/tag combo already exists, it seems to untag the original image, upload the new one, and apply the tag to the new one.

This is leading to my repo becoming bloating with lots of untagged versions of the same image.

How do I test if the image/tag combo already exist in `gcr.io`, so that I only push when it's required?

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I solved this in a shell script

```sh
existing_tags=$(gcloud container images list-tags --filter="tags:mytag" --format=json gcr.io/myproject/myimage)

if [[ "$existing_tags" == "[]" ]]; then
  printf "tag does not exist"
else
  printf "tag exists"
fi
```

**Explanation**

I'm using `gcloud container images list-tags` ([documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/list-tags))

- And filtering for tags matching `mytag` using the `--filter` flag
- And formatting as JSON using `--format=json`

So essentially, if the tag `mytag` *doesn't* exist, the output of this will be an empty array `[]`, otherwise, it does exist. You can test this really simply just by string comparison in your script, and then proceed accordingly.

Comment: Note if you don't use JSON formatting, you'll get "Listed 0 images." message when no results. With JSON it's much easier to check `[]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1:** Assuming your `docker` command has the gcr credentials, you can try to pull the image like `docker pull gcr.io/foo/image:tag`. This would be slow, but it's a guaranteed way.

**Method 2:** Assuming `gcloud` is present in your environment, you could run `gcloud container images list-tags [- -format=json] gcr.io/foo/image` and see if the output has the `tag` you want.

**Method 3:** If these two solutions aren't good enough for you, you can learn how to use your Google Cloud Service Account as a docker username/password [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication), and then use the [Docker Registry v2 API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) to [List Image Tags](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags) or just directly [Query the image manifest for pulling the image](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#pulling-an-image) with the `tag`.

For example, if you had an `gcr.io/foo/alpine:v1` image, to test this using cURL and a temporary `access_token` (obtained via gcloud), you could run:

```
TOKEN="$(gcloud config config-helper --format 'value(credential.access_token)')"

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    https://gcr.io/v2/foo/alpine/manifests/v1
```

and if you get an 200 OK response, it means that tag exists.

Comment: Is there an equivalent curl command for GAR?

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can check using `gcloud`:

```
gcloud container images describe ${GCR_URL}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} > /dev/null ; echo $?
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest solution. No need to check for empty arrays and you get an exit code. Brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few good answers above. But I just wanna give 1 more option that I'm using.

```
#!/bin/bash

REPO_URL=gcr.io/myproject/myimage
TAG=mytag

TAG_EXISTING="$(gcloud container images list-tags --format='get(tags)' $REPO_URL | grep $TAG)"
if [ -z $TAG_EXISTING ]
then
    docker push $REPO_URL:$TAG
fi
```

Comment: If you have a lot of tags for one image this is not working as there will be multiple pages